# Calabash cucumber: command not found - cucumber not in /usr/bin

Tags: macos, rubygems, cucumber, calabash

I have an issue with cucumber. I've reviews all of the other StackOverflow answers and none of them exactly match my own scenario.

I'm running the following line of code in a Unix script, which should run Calabash Cucumber (to allow Calabash to drive the iOS simulator on Mac OSX:

```
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (9.1)' APP=./myapp.app cucumber
```

I get the following error when the above line runs:

```
cucumber: command not found
```

The issue seems to be that cucumber isn't installed into the root `/usr/bin` folder (this doesn't contain a 'cucumber' folder as expected). I install calabash cucumber using

```
sudo gem install calabash-cucumber -v 0.16.4
```

I can see that I have cucumber itself installed in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/bin`, and I've added that to my path by editing my .bash_profile, and the 'cucumber' command then works, however for the system I'm working on I get a whole set of different errors, since cucumber is really expected to be available in the `/usr/bin` directory.

I've installed calabash cucumber on other computers (running El Capitan, the same OS that I have the problem with), and cucumber is successfully installed into `/usr/bin`.

Uninstalling and re-installing calabash-cucumber doesn't work. What can I do to ensure cucumber is installed into `/usr/bin`? I suspect this is somehow permissions related (and I've disabled system integrity checking on the machine, however, this makes no difference).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Xcode 8.0 and/or macOS Sierra, Calabash no longer supports using the Apple system ruby.

We recommend using `rbenv`.

Here is some documentation:

- [Never install gems with sudo](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Best-Practice%3A--Never-install-gems-with-sudo)
- [Ruby on macOS](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Ruby-on-MacOS)
- [rbenv guide](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/rbenv-guide)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by removing all existing versions of cucumber gems from my system (I needed to remove these from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/), using:

```
sudo gem uninstall cucumber -v 1.3.18 (or whatever version number you're using)
```

then I re-installed Calabash Cucumber using:

```
sudo gem install calabash-cucumber -v 0.16.4
```

The latest version of Cucumber was then successfully installed in /usr/bin, and everything now works.

Comment: It is not recommend to install gems with `sudo`.